# Scheme :Dealing with lists within lists

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm using Scheme (Racket) for the first time, and I am having some problems. I want to know how I can manipulate lists within lists (specifically print the head of each sublist)

I know how to print the head of the superlist (which is a list itself)

eg:

```
 (define (concatenate list-a)
   (car list-a))
```

Now if I input:

```
(concatenate '(("one" "two") ("three" "four") ("five" "six")))
```

Then I get

```
'("one" "two")
```

But what I want to get is: `"one" "three" "five"`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `car` to every element (sublist) of the main list, using `map`:

```
(define (concatenate lst)
  (map car lst))

(concatenate '(("one" "two") ("three" "four") ("five" "six")))
=> '("one" "three" "five")
```

To print these values each on its own line, use `for-each`:

```
(for-each displayln (concatenate '(("one" "two") ("three" "four") ("five" "six"))))
=> 
one
three
five
```

You could also use `map` instead of `for-each`, but then you'd get

```
one
three
five
'(#<void> #<void> #<void>)
```

The trailing `'(#<void> #<void> #<void>)` is the result of applying `displayln` to each value (`displayln` always returns *void*). So use `map` if you care about the result, `for-each` if you don't.

Comment: Ok I have another question. What if I want to append a string like "hello" to each element in the list. How do I do this? Since string-append only works on strings and not lists.

Comment: `(map (lambda (e) (string-append e " hello")) '("Jack" "John" "Paul"))`

Comment: Thanks! But Im gonna check out lambda again though

Comment: In Racket, you can also `(map (curryr string-append " hello") '("Jack" "John" "Paul"))`.